# Trigger that check number of elements inserted in an array

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

There is a MODEL table as follow

```
create table MODEL (
model_name VARCHAR(20),
model_year NUMBER,
consumption VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
Component component_ty_nt,
Distributor distributor_ty_nt,
Car car_ty_nt,
constraint t_pk primary key (Model_Name, Model_Year))
nested table Component store as component_ty_nt_TAB
nested table Distributor store as distributor_ty_nt_TAB
nested table Car store as car_ty_nt_TAB
```

the Component_ty

```
Create or replace type Component_ty as object (
Code VARCHAR(10),
Component_Description VARCHAR(100),
Component_Type VARCHAR(10))
NOT FINAL;
```

has component_type attribute which can be 'body', 'engine' or 'equipment'

Every time I perform an INSERT on this table I need a trigger that checks that there are at least 3 components inserted, for which 1 must be of type 'engine' and one must be of type 'body'.
Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

for what concern the number of components (at least 3) I just wrote this trigger

```
create or replace trigger number_of_components 
after insert on Model
for each row
declare
componentNumber NUMBER;
BEGIN 
select 
c.component_number INTO componentNumber from model m
outer apply (select count(*) as component_number from table(component)) c
where m.model_name = :new.model_name AND m.model_year = :new.model_year;
if componentNumber < 3 then
    raise_application_error(-2061, 'Not enough components');
end if;
end;
```

but it returns those errors:

```
ora-04091: table DB_EXAM.Model it mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ora-06512: at "DB_EXAM.NUMBER_OF_COMPONENT", line 4
ora-04088: error during execution of trigger'DB_EXAM.NUMBER_OF_COMPONENT'
```

what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

For what concern the trigger to check that ONLY 1 component is of type 'Engine' and ONLY 1 is of type 'Body', I've tried with the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_engine_and_body
BEFORE INSERT ON model
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
engineCounter NUMBER;
bodyCounter NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..:new.Component.COUNT LOOP
    IF deref(:new.Component(i)).Component_Type = 'Engine' THEN
      engineCounter := engineCounter + 1;
    ELSIF deref(:new.Component(i)).Component_Type = 'Body' THEN
      bodyCounter := bodyCounter + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF engineCounter != 1 OR bodyCounter != 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Constraint violated, too many values');
  END IF;
END;
```

but I get error:
PL/SQL: Statement ignore
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DEREF'

How to fix?

Comment: Since you are using nested tables to load the multiple component types, a basic row level trigger on the model table would suffice.

Comment: Paul W  Check out for the update

Comment: Don't query the table in the trigger... instead, access :new.component using PL/SQL loop and check your business rule against it. Since you are using nested tables, a single row insert contains a collection and as I understand it, it's amid that collection that you want to enforce your row count constraint.

Comment: could you please show an example, I can't really understand how to do it

Comment: I put it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
create or replace trigger number_of_components 
after insert on Model
for each row
BEGIN 
  IF :new.component.COUNT < 3
  THEN
    raise_application_error(-20061, 'Not enough components');
  END IF;
END;
```

Note that I also corrected your error number by adding an extra 0 digit. You can of course build on this to add in your checks for specific component types.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. thanks for adding the 0.
Any clue on how can I check the type constraint, one of type 'engine', 1 of type 'body'?

Comment: Paul W Check for update 2!

Comment: Don't use DEREF. Also make sure to initialize your counters at 0. null + 1 is still null.

Comment: without the deref it returns those errors: 6/5 PL/SQL : Statement ignore 6/26 PLS-00536: Navigation through REF variables is not supported in PL/SQL

Comment: I'm afraid I have never used DEREF so I cannot be of further help. You'll have to study the Oracle docs on it and determine whether you are using it correctly or not. I was assuming your collection contained data, not REF pointers.